# How can I change style/color of one shape without changing all of them?

Tags: shapes, sketch-app

I'm new to sketch and would like to have two of the same shape, but I want one of the shapes to be white and the other one black. As soon as I edit one of the shapes, the other one changes as well. How can I "unlink" the two shapes? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Both items are probably used [Shared styles](https://www.sketchapp.com/support/documentation/05-text/3-text-styles.html), which means the properties are linked.

To unlink just, on the right hand sude, under the object properties, choose "no shared style" under the styles dropdown

[image: Sketch shared styles dropdown]

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. @Tara if that doesn't work, check to make sure they aren't both instances of the same symbol. They will have purple icons in the Layers List, or you can right-click one of them and if "Detach from symbol" is at the bottom of the menu, click that to separate them.